# Facebook Like button getting disappeared when clicked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The like button is getting disappeared when user clicks on the button.
Code used

```
<div id="fb-root" style="display:none">1</div>
    <script>
      (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="winefacebook" style="float:left;">
      <fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" >.</fb:like>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this isue?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand Facebook Like button is now working with problems because of some minor system issues. This bug is reported quite often at their support forum. I'm afraid you can't really do anything with this until they will fix this.
The only thing I can suggest is to check your site with their debugger http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
Good luck.